# How to make buttons appear after ProgressBar loads?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and started making my own program. How ever, I want these (https://gyazo.com/8b4e0f4141b15e1ff204e1cfc8f41827) to disappear until my progress bar loads (https://gyazo.com/5064ebd9582593942c6e538e1ae516dc). I tried to use Visible but got nowhere.

ProgressBar code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.timer1.Start();
}

private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var before = this.progressBar1.Value;
    this.progressBar1.Increment(1);
    var after = this.progressBar1.Value;

    if (after > before && after == this.progressBar1.Maximum)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully loaded...");
        this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.image1;              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "Form.Load" set Image.Visible = false and when you are showing the MessageBox set Image.Visible = true

Comment: Here you can check out the life cycle of a WinForm app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms